# There is a convention for the use of the sentence ":foo => 'bar'" or "foo: 'bar' " in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, coding-style

Is there a convention for the use of `=>` or `:` in Ruby 1.9+? like:

```
:param => "foo"
```

or

```
param: "foo"
```

EDIT: Thanks for the feedback, I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: FYI:  This has nothing to do with rails.  It's a Ruby 1.9 change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a difference; The newer "JSON" style of hash creation can only be used with symbol keys. Demonstrated below.

```
{ param: "foo" }
```

is equivalent to

```
{ :param => "foo" }
```

So you cannot use it to create this hash:

```
{ "foo" => "bar" }
```

Or this one:

```
{ 0 => "One" }
```

This makes a lot of sense, since it is best practice to use symbol keys when you can.

Edit:
Also in your example, `{ param => "foo" }` the value of the variable param will be used as the key.

so

```
param = :foo
{ param => "bar" }
```

is equivalent to

```
{ :foo => "bar" }
```

Comment: Might also note that `{param: "foo"}` IS NOT THE SAME AS `{param => "foo"}`.  The former is using a symbol `:param` key, the latter is using the value of a variable as the key.

Comment: *Some* symbol keys, consider `:$set => { ... }` and `$set: { ... }` which is a fairly common thing to do when working with MongoDB.

Comment: True. And anything you would have to quote in a regular symbol, and :@var, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I heard in a tutorial from codeschool.com that it was exactly the same. `params:` its just as intuitive as `params =>` but you get to save three chacters... (Two spaces between `=>` and a character )

Comment: Exactly the same except that `{'params'=>'foo'} # => {
    "params" => "foo"
}` and `{params:'foo'} # => {
    :params => "foo"
}`. One's a String for a key and the other is a Symbol. The differences from that point expand even farther due to efficiencies in memory use and speed of lookups.